# django-pipeline js compressor is not working

Tags: python, django, django-pipeline

This is my settings.py looks like :

```
kProjectRoot = abspath(normpath(join(dirname(__file__), '..')))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(kProjectRoot, 'abc/media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',

    'south',
    'xlrd',
    'pipeline',
    )

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY='C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/yuicompressor-2.4.8-py2.7.egg/yuicompressor'

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'site': {
    'source_filenames': (
        'media/js/zk.base.js',
        'media/js/zk.popupmenu.js',
        'media/js/zk.tree.js',
        'media/js/zk.treenode.js',
    ),
    'output_filename': 'media/js/script.min.js',
    }
}
```

What is the mistake i am doing , please guide me . I think that it should create a `script.min.js` in my `media/js/` , which i can load in `templates`.

Comment: yep, same problem. It's only can be reproduced under Windows

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

If that doesn't work, make sure these are in your `settings.py` and run `collectstatic` again, your assets will be under the `build` folder.

`PIPELINE_ENABLED = True`

`STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'pipeline.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
)`

```
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'build'))

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

Then you can use your assets by putting the following in your template:

```
{% load compressed %}
{% compressed_js 'site' %}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace back-slashes `\` with forward-slashes `/` in the path of `PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY`.

Comment: No improvement after this change :(